# Почему не получается залить большой backup 130GB на S3?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Привет. Нужна помощь с проблемой заливки большого бекапа на S3 (aws). Проблема в том что отваливается с ошибкой `Connection reset by peer` . Как починить? Спасибо

Полный выхлоп

`10001 0 5242880
10001 57344 5242880
10005 0 5242880
10005 57344 5242880
10002 0 5242880
10002 57344 5242880
10002 114688 5242880
10002 172032 5242880
10003 0 5242880
10003 57344 5242880
10003 0 5242880
10003 57344 5242880
10006 0 5242880
10006 57344 5242880
10003 0 5242880
10003 57344 5242880
10006 0 5242880
10006 57344 5242880
10006 0 5242880
10006 57344 5242880
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/s3upload", line 9, in 
    load_entry_point('s3upload==0.2.4', 'console_scripts', 's3upload')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/s3upload.py", line 161, in cli
    progress_cb=cb, replace=True, threads=options.threads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/s3upload.py", line 111, in upload
    waiter()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/s3upload.py", line 98, in waiter
    check_errors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/s3upload.py", line 94, in check_errors
    raise exc
thread.error:  error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')
ERROR: Failed to pack application data!`

Команда которой выполняю архивацию и загрузку. (p.s. - есть архив 40гб, заливает нормально)

`/bin/tar --exclude "imageupload/images" -cf - -C /var/www/blabla.com/www/ . | gzip| s3upload -K KEY -s secretkey -b archive -k test.tar.gz`

Ubuntu 14 x64

Comment: не проще ли разбить архив на несколько частей?

Comment: *есть архив 40гб* — наверняка это уже готовый файл, путь к которому вы передаёте программе s3upload (кстати, что это за программа, откуда вы её взяли и какой версии?), и она может передать серверу информацию о размере файла. а в вопросе вы пытаетесь передать поток байт неизвестной длины. либо сформируйте файл и копируйте его, либо попытайтесь воспользоваться т.н. [multipart upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuJava.html) (как сказать это вашей программе — см. документацию к ней).

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/s3upload/0.2.4

это питонячая тула. она не умеет мультипарт. архив в 40гб так же делается на лету.

Comment: пробовал разбивать. пока он его разбивает происходит тот же самый reset.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Починил тем что изменил код самой тулы. Добавил туда разбивку по 100 мегабайт и все терь пашет. По умолчанию у нее чанк по 5мегабайт.

Comment: значит, можете багрепорт разработчикам отправлять. хотя, наверно, правильней было бы добавить возможность указывать произвольный размер отправляемого блока.